# Liberation and religions

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, free-will

Religion is always for a group; but philosophy is not so. One person alone cannot be a religion. It is quite natural that there is *a bond (a feeling of my and my men) among the members of a religion* and bondage also.

**If liberation is the aim** of a religion, is it necessary to break this bond/bondage also for liberation (before or after death)?

If 'no', can we call it liberation?

Doesn't this imply that religions (**not philosophy**) never suggest liberation / total liberation?

Is it possible in any other way?

Comment: "Force of attraction", like what, gravity? "Liberation is the aim", whose aim? Could you fill in the in between the lines to anchor your loose analogies, so it doesn't sound like you are talking about gravitational accretion and escape velocities.

Comment: You introduce an idiosyncratic aim for religion, and then an idiosyncratic analysis of the relationships between members of a religion, and then ask us to explain how they work together? What?

Comment: I would say you're right, religion is not about liberation and for the reasons you give. This is a common complaint against religion. As the Rig Veda says, 'Beware the hymn-reciters'. The full notion of liberation is heretical in commonplace monotheism, and this is connected with the persecution of Meister Eckhart and Al-Halaj. . ..  .

Comment: @Conifold: Thanks for your comments. I have made some edits. You may verify it if you like.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Thanks for your comment.  I realize your feeling from your words. I didn't under estimate religions. Please don't misunderstand me. My main question is not about the **principles of religion**. You may verify the words given in bold letters. I was asking about its aim (the final) and the contradiction in saying so. I believe a true believer will get peace of mind from his religion.  I have only very limited knowledge about religions. Kindly post your ideas an answer if you like.

Comment: It seems like your question might be better suited for theological circles, but if you're going to talk about religion and the West, you should familiarize yourself with [liberation theology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_theology) which is a reaction against the use of Christianity as a tool of centralization, dogmatization, and authortarianism. In essence, many have noticed that the Christian message has essentially been coopted by the same empire-like political organization it emerged to overturn.

Comment: In Buddhism, the final step to enlightenment requires that you liberate yourself from all earthly ties (even from the desire to liberate yourself). So here is a religion which advocates liberation. I would also deny that one person cannot hold their own religion; why ever not? When a holy man first starts teaching a major new insight, are they not the only adherent of their newfound religion?

Comment: @PeterJ: Thank you for the good pieces of information you shared. I have only very little knowledge about religions. But I am aware of the bad deeds done by exploiting nature and the poor as for the sake of religion and God.

Comment: @JD; I went through the link you gave. It was new to me. Thanks.  I believe you tried to categorize me.  Didn't try to go deep into the question.  I was trying to ask a doubt about a contradiction I could find. Would you please explain where I went wrong?

Comment: @SonOfThought - Your question is not clear on what you mean by 'liberation', which might cause some confusion. It has a social/political meaning and a metaphysical/fundamental meaning. You might like to check-out Sadhguru on youtube talking about religion. He probably shares your view and it is orthodox in some quarters. The difficulty, again, is defining 'religion' since it has too many meanings.  .

Comment: @SonOfThought I'm an empiricist and reject the presumptions of the question. Religion as I understand it is a social activity which accomplishes different things for different peoples; Your framework is so broad, it's almost meaningless to me. What is religion? What is liberation? What is bondage? Your question is essentially a vague metaphor for education. I'd commit to this: evolution equips us with the capacity to learn at the genetic, epigenetic, and psychological levels. We strive to liberate ourselves from ignorance, the confinement of dominance hierarchies, and from our own suffering.

Comment: @Peter: I mean that the fundamental meaning that can liberate metaphysically, socially and politically as well. If this is the video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsczX7_MVCA ) it doesn't answer my question because it is about belief.  My question is about a contradiction.  I admit the thing you mentioned about the difficulty in defining religion.

Comment: @JD: If somebody is liberated from ignorance about oneself he must be a person who is liberated from other things also.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few misconceptions underlying this question that I want to straighten out before trying to answer it.

First, religion and philosophy are not the distinct entities the question presumes. Religion is the *codification* of philosophy. Every religion begins with the philosophical insight of a particular teacher. That philosophical teaching is gathered into a liturgy; solidified with a set of practices and injunctions; embellished with art, ritual, rites, and other aesthetic manifestations. The end result is religion. Over time religion may lose track of the underlying philosophical insights, at least for the bulk of the congregation: religious leaders can become more invested in their status and authority than in a faithful pursuit of the core philosophy, and congregations can collapse into lip-service practice, or focus on the dogmatic letter of the teaching rather than the living spirit of it. But while the philosophical core of religion might be reduced to esoteric mysticism, it never goes away entirely.

We have to take a bit of care with the notion of 'liberation.' Liberation is a *soteriology*: a theory about how to save ourselves from (to quote Hamlet) "the heartache, and the thousand natural shocks that flesh is heir to." The problem is that while 'soteriology' is a general concept — we all want to find salvation from the miseries that life lades on us — 'liberation' is a more specific. To talk about 'liberation' we have to talk about what we need to be liberated *from*, and that can pull different philosophies off into various directions. *True* liberation (if I can speak of that) is a difficult concept: it implies freedom from both social *and* psychological constraints; it isn't purely individualistic or purely communitarian, but both and neither at the same time. So on one hand we end up with philosophers like Nietzsche, who suggest that *all* received morality is (at best) incomplete or (at worst) corrupt, and that we must liberate ourselves from those teachings and transcend them to find authentic moral positions. On the other hand, we find original teachers like Christ, who suggest that we only truly find ourselves in service and love to others, and need to liberate ourselves from the petty egoic concerns that lead us to fight and steal and lust.

Obviously, philosophers like Nietzsche do *not* tend to foster the creation of organized religions — though they can develop cultish followings among people who dogmatize their writing — and people like Christ *do* tend to foster such. But that is more a concern of the tendencies of followers than of the actual philosophies themselves.

If we exclude malignant cults (groups formed by people intent on dominating a smallish group of followers), then every founder of every religion intended to teach a system of liberation. Fully developed religions may (and often do) lose track of that. They may end up treating their congregations as flocks that need to be guided, not as people who need to be liberated, and they may do that for the best of misguided reasons. In that case, one eventually needs to see *through* their faith to the deeper teaching, and to transcend the structural limitations that the faith places on them (ostensibly for their own good). This is similar to the process that a child goes through as it enters adulthood: a child must break off from the container that parents create for it in order to return as an equal. It's in that 'returning as an equal' that liberation is found.

Comment: I liked the presentation and most of the ideas you shared. Thanks. (+1)  Your idea is based on, "Religion is the codification of philosophy."~ Since the followers should abide by the rules of their religion, if any philosophy says even codification may lead to bond, would that philosophy be codified to become a religion? You may check thoroughly whether this philosophy about codification is rational/true.  In other words, if this is true, "Religions won't tell you the underlying philosophy completely." And this implies, "Religions won't tell you the Truth completely."

Comment: @SonOfThought: If we're going to follow William James, or Huxely's *Perennial Philosophy*, the problem isn't that 'religions lie'; the problem is that each generation of followers understands the original teaching less: garbled transmission. Eventually a new teacher comes along who has *the same* insight as the original teacher (in somewhat different words), who tries to do a course correction. Sometimes they pull the faith back on course; sometimes they create a schism and a new faith arises. then the garbling starts again.

Comment: @SonOfThought: Codification of a philosophy doesn't necessarily lead to religion. For instance, Marxism, Right-Libertarianism, and even (if I can stretch the definition of 'philosophy' a good bit) professional sports are ritualized, dogmatized, and even subject to artistic paeans (Ayn Rand's novels, Marxist murals, sports merchandizing). Two of those are expressly anti-religious and the third likes its Sundays free. It has more to do with the nature of the philosophy: hyper-individualist philosophies generally abhor organized religion.

Comment: OK. Different philosophies treat liberation in different ways. Even if the teachings of each new teacher is about **true liberation (fundamental)**, he can make use of that philosophy as philosophy; but not as a religion.  This is the thing I am talking about. Even though there are many benefits, here (in this question) the topic is not about benefits of religion; but true liberation and religions.  Thank you for your great effort for answering this question nicely.

Comment: @SonOfThought: Hm. The distinction you're making between philosophy and religion seems a little strange from my perspective. It feels like you're coming down decidedly on the Nietzschean side of things, and thus only see the limitations of the *other* side, not *your* side. In other words, you're trying to suggest that religion inhibits liberation, but don't realize that the the independent philosophical approach can be just as inhibiting, for different reasons. You've run smack into the problematic of mysticism without realizing it, and I'm unsure how to bring that into focus.

Comment: What I am saying is not "religion inhibits liberation". I am saying that religions won't tell/demand you to do it...I mean, religions won't say "liberate yourself from everything--including the bond with religion." When you use the word 'inhibit', there is an opposing force. But I didn't mean any kind of **opposing force** here. The attachment is of the follower due to the hidden truth /  the truth unsaid. Now I believe you won't say that I see only the limitation of the other side :) I agree with the last two ideas you shared.  Thanks.

Comment: @SonOfThought: Actually, you'll find that exact statement in a lot of mystical sects: Buddhism, Gnosticism, Sufism, Vedanta, I believe in Kabbalah; Crowley made it the centerpiece of Thelema, and Emerson the heart of Transcendentalism (though it's odd to mention those two in the same sentence). it's usually considered an 'advanced' teaching, but it's there. Liturgical sects don't go into it for the same reasons that parents don't normally tell young children about sex, death, and taxes. One needs to develop into the concept.

Comment: @SonOfThought: sorry for any confusion; or posts got crossed somehow, so I deleted mine and reposted an hour later. But I still don't think you see the weakness of Nietzschean/existentialist/phenomenological philosophical approach, because you haven't mentioned anything about it at all. You've been quite focused on religious aspects.

Comment: I had mentioned about your two ideas in my last comment.  Don't worry at all...you have reposted it.  To avoid confusions in the users I shall repeat/quote those two ideas: "Liturgical sects don't go into it for the same reasons that parents don't normally tell young children about sex, death, and taxes. One needs to develop into the concept."

Comment: Great, Ted Wrigley.  If I couldn't accept your ideas with a smile before you say sorry it must be the defect of the ideals I follow.  I focused on the logical aspect as well as religious aspect.  In the pursuit of Truth you could understand the commonness in different religions.  Blessed you are.  I wish your ideas stay here always and guide the Truth seekers of all religions.  I also wish the prayers of the people of all religions to liberate from Covid 19 (also) go deeper especially in this periods of miseries and vanish the conflicts between religions. Thanks, Good bye.